# Creating chunking system in Godot with tilemaps. Interesting problem with loops

Tags: c#, godot, godot4

Godot: v4.1.1
Built using Forward+ mode

Some background:
I have a chunk manager class that has a Dictionary<>, ActiveChunks (which I should probably change to a List<>), and a Queue, InactiveChunks, so that I can hibernate old unused chunks so that they could be recycled later. As of now, I have the entire in-game map set to be active in the manager subscriptions as I haven't implemented world anchors yet (I want to get a good handful of other things done first, such as inventory which I will probably use to implement that).

The problem:
In the manager _Process method, I have a while loop that is *supposed* to count down to 0 from the number of chunk subscriptions minus the number of active chunks as it adds on TileMap UIs from the InactiveChunks queue, but it instead counts down by one and then the count gets stuck in some sort of infinite loop where it no longer decrements, but there are no nested loops inside and it doesn't seem to leave the loop. I am sort of at a loss for words.

I managed to replicate this issue in a test project, which can be found at the link below. Hopefully this will be easier read and work with than trying to paste all the code here.

https://github.com/stevetheburger/ChunkTest.git

If one has issues trying to obtain the code, please let me know.

Thanks.

P.S. Updated dictionary to be list. Different flavor of problem. May self resolve tomorrow. See comments for details.

Comment: Just took my own advice and updated the ActiveObjects dictionary to be a list instead. It does seem to eliminate the issue of the count not proceeding, as the line 55 in the manager seemed to be the offender. No idea why that would cause that issue and I would think Godot would like to know that there is a problem if attempting to insert into a dictionary inside of a loop is causing the loop to get stuck somehow.

Comment: There is still a problem where it seems that the location for all the objects is at the bottom right corner (which would be 99,99 in the example). It is late and I will resume looking at this after lunch tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that a local variable was being assigned to the data and C# was doing it by reference without me knowing it. Had to step away for a while and come back to realize it. Still no idea why the dictionary doesn't work, but I don't need it anyway.